# Flask SQLAlchemy query: filter records from self foreign key relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model class with self ForeignKey relation like this:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(db.String(320))
    status = Column(db.Integer) # 0: undone, 1:done
    parent_id = Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('foo.id'), index=True)
    parent = db.relationship(lambda: Foo, remote_side=id, backref='sub_foo')
```

I need to filter rows that have either no child or all done (`status == 1`) children.
In other words I need to exclude rows that have children with undone (`status == 0`) status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to perform `EXISTS` queries is to use the `any()` and `has()` methods of relationships:

```
# Note the use of ~ operator for NOT
Foo.query.filter(~Foo.sub_foo.any(status=0))
```

`any()` accepts either SQL boolean expressions as positional arguments, or keyword arguments as shorthands for simple equality comparisons.